# Inbox and Notifications aren't being filtered by site

Tags: bug, api-v2.1, inbox, notifications

I'm using the API get inbox messages and notifications for various sites on the StackExchange network, but it doesn't seem to matter what `site` parameter I pass in the query string. I always get my global inbox. The following all return the same for me.

```
/2.1/me/inbox?site=stackoverflow

/2.1/me/inbox?site=stackapps

/2.1/me/inbox?site=windowsphone
```

Is this a bug? I don't think I'm doing anything silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [in the `/me/inbox` documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-inbox), the route is

> ...effectively an alias for [/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox). It is provided for consumers who make strong assumptions about operating within the context of a single site rather than the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

Since it's just more or less a convenience route for the global `/inbox` method, it doesn't actual behave as a per-site route and no filtering by site is performed. If you want to filter the items at the site level, you'll have to process the full set of results and just pick out what you want.

Comment: Cheers - didn't spot that sentence. What is the point of the site parameter then? I mean, what's the point of me making it clear to the API what context I'm using the inbox for?

Comment: The documentation is confusing in this case. `/users/{id}/inbox/unread` is listed under Per-Site Methods section, which says `Each of these methods operates on a single site at a time, identified by the site parameter`. And as @Spencerooni said, `site` parameter is confusing also.